# Using a subset of a QVector in a function

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

How to send a portion of a QVector to a function?

```
QVector<int> a;
a.append(1);
a.append(2);
a.append(3);
a.append(4);
a.append(5);
```

Some printing function should print "2 3 4" taking the subset of the vector as an argument.

In R this would be possible using `a[2:4]`.

Is this at all possible?

Note: In the `std::vector`, it is advised to use the `insert` function to create a new variable. This is a different insert though than `QVector` has, and thus I cannot find a recommended method.

Comment: Based on a very quick look at the docs it doesn't seem to be possible. At least not in any concise way. Perhaps you should use std::vector instead of QVector. It seems to have a better interface.

Comment: @john The problem is that I will be using a QCustomPlot which expects a QVector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I must write at least 30 characters so I can tell you, you should try:

```
a.mid(1,3);
```

Comment: Wow, something so simple. I am surprised it is so easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a function to do this operation for you, e.g.

```
QVector<int> sub_vector(const QVector<int>& vec, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    QVector<int> subvec;
    for (size_t i = from; i <= to; ++i)
        subvec.append(vec[i]);
    return subvec;
}
```

Comment: Appending seems like a slow solution?

Comment: Is performance critical? You could add a call to reserve I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you must pass a pair of iterators (begin and end of the range you want, you can use std::pair to pass only one argument or use a clearer method that take two `QVector::iterator` arguments and that way it's clearer that you meant that function to take a range) or if it's simpler to you (or the elements you want are not in continuous order in original QVector) construct another QVector that contains only the selected elements (kind of the solution proposed by *john*).